# How can I make Redstone respond to a player having no money in their account?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone, minecraft-bukkit

I am building a gambling machine on a Bukkit server with the Vault plugin, and I would like to do an error check. When the player wants to play the game, they need to have X dollars in their bank account. If they have less than the amount they want to bet, they should not be able to place a bet.

Is there any way to get a Redstone flag to be true if the player has enough money in their account to place the bet they want to place (or false if they don't)?

Comment: There is no money in Minecraft. Please add "mods" or "bukkit" to tags, and clarify.

Comment: @OrcJMR The OP could be using XP or Scoreboard to keep track of money though.

Comment: @mrfishie Damm, scoreboards, right. Still, nothing can be said until clarified.

Answer (score 3):

You sound like you're making a whole new mini-game for a minecraft bukkit server, with a vault compatible economy plugin. 
For something like this, I'd recommend using http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/variabletriggers/ to make scripts to complete your desired action.

If you're coding a plugin by hand, and need some help making it, post [here](http://forums.bukkit.org/forums/plugin-development.5/).

Comment: I am making a game within a game. It is a bukkit server and we do have some kind of vault plugin. You are the second person that has mentioned these variable triggers and scripting. I am not coding a plugin. I thank you for linking me.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a players [XP](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Experience) as money, the following command in a [command block](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Command_block) will output a signal if the nearest player has no XP to a [comparator](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_comparator):

```
/testfor @p[l=0]
```

Alternatively, if you are using the new [Scoreboard](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard) to keep track of money, you can find if the nearest player has a score of zero in the objective `money` with this command:

```
/testfor @p[money=0]
```

You can replace the text `money` with the internal name of the objective you are using to keep track of money.

If you are using something else, like a Bukkit plugin or a mod, please clarify this in your question, including the plugin/mod that you are using.

Comment: I apologize, I was not very specific. It's a bukkit server with a vault plugin. I am going to have to explore the /testfor command.

Comment: @rmarenda You will probably not have any luck with the `/testfor` command if you are using a plugins. I haven't seen any plugins that add arguments to be used with command blocks.